# Python name mangling allows access both ways

Tags: python, python-3.x, private, member, name-mangling

So I have come across a very interesting behavior of python name mangling.
Consider the following code

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__c = 1
    
    @staticmethod
    def change(instance):
        print(dir(instance))
        print(instance.__c)
        print(instance._C__c)
```

Here I create a private field __c and expect to have direct access to it from within class and access via _C__c from outside of the class. So, if we pass an instance of C to C.change either 2nd or 3rd print should fail.
Lets check:

```py
>>> c =  C()
>>> dir(c)
['_C__c', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'change']
>>> C.change(c)
['_C__c', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'change']
1
1
```

First, for debug we print all available members of c with `dir(c)`. Then we call C.change passing it the variable `c`.
Hmm, that is unexpected, no errors.
So, first print in `change` shows us all the available entries of the `instance` object. Here we see that field `__c` is available as `_C__c`. That seems ok, since we access not through self, but through another variable.
Having such output from 'dir' I expect `print(instance.__c)` to fail with AttributeError.
However, unexpectedly, it works just fine!
This really confuses me, since I do not understand, why is `__c` accessible and if it is so by design, then why is it not listed in `dir` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you write `__c` inside a class, it will be textually replaced by `_<classname>__c`. It's not dynamically performed, it's done at the parsing stage. Hence, the interpreter won't ever see `__c`, only `_<classname>__c`. That's why only `_C__c` appears in `dir(instance)`.

Quoting [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers):

> [...] Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named `Ham` will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`. This transformation is independent of the syntactical context in which the identifier is used. [...]

For that reason, it only applies to dotted attribute access (`x.y`), not to dynamic access via `(get|set)attr`:

```py
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         setattr(self, '__x', 'test')
... 
>>> Foo().__x
'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

`__`-prefixed names work fine as-is *inside* the class's own methods. It's only *outside* the class (including in its subclasses) that the modified name is needed to access the attribute, due to [name-mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers).

Comment: Then why is it not listed in `dir(instance)` when I call it inside the change method?

Comment: @VladimirVislovich Whenever you write `__c` inside a class, it will be *textually* replaced by `_<classname>__c`. It's not dynamically performed, it's done at the parsing stage. That's why only `_C__c` appears in `dir(instance)`.

Comment: @a_guest ooh, now that makes sense! Probably you should make your comment an answer to the question as it really is one